# How to make C# class know about HTML control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, htmlcontrols

I have a .aspx file with:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="baa.foo" CodeFile="foo.aspx.cs" %>
<input runat="server" id="name" name="name" />
```

and `foo.aspx.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace baa
{
    public partial class foo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = name.Text;
        }
    }
```

How do I to `name` HTML control be know by `foo` class in `.cs` file? it returns an error:

> Error 61  The name 'name' does not exist in the current context

NOTE: The HTML was not written by me. I'm editing .html pages to .aspx ones to make them dymically and I be able to get values from them by using C# code

Comment: Turn the <input> tag into a server control like <asp:Textbox> and the code-behind page should be able to access its properties.

Comment: `<input runat='server'/>` must be placed in side the `<form runat='server'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, HTML elements within an ASP.NET file are treated as
>   literal text and you cannot reference them in server-side code. To
>   make these elements programmatically accessible, you can indicate that
>   an HTML element should be treated as a server control by adding the
>   **runat="server"** attribute.

and Also

> HTML server controls must reside within a containing **form** tag with the
>   **runat="server"** attribute.

Reference: [HTML Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/620b4fzf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Now you can access your control from code behind but here you can't get `Text` property of `input` html control, you need to get `Value` property.

If you convert html page to ASPX then you can replace relevant ASP.NET control with existing HTML controls. for example you can use input type text with [ASP.NET TextBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use `name.value` instead of `name.text`

Comment: That will not work. The error is: `The name 'name' does not exist in the current context`